# Processing applet in browser, 'init failed unsupported os'

Tags: java, macos, opengl, applet, jogl

I'm getting familiar with processing and I currently have a working environment set up with eclipse and eclipsep5exporter.

I successfully run my projects and export them to native applications, however, exporting applets that run in the browser has proven to be a real pickle.

Currently I have a Java applet in the browser that gives me the error:

```
error init failed unsupported os arch mac os x x86 64
```

I've searched the internet and found hints about `JOGLAppletLauncher` being the villain when it comes to this issue. However I'd love to hear from someone else before I look into it further.

Also if anyone can get it to run on a different system than mine, please let me know.

http://augustbjornberg.com/dir/workspace/applet/index.html

Comment: Tested now on Windows, and it doesn't throw the error mentioned above. It would be nice to get this working on OSX though, if anyone has ideas  I am still very eager to hear them, thanks! /Ag

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you were supposed to do that, I'll look into it, thanks Andrew.

Comment: *"didn't know"*  We learn as we go. *"you were supposed to do that"*  It is not really a 'supposed to' so much as a tip.  :)